# how to change devexpress xtragrid autofiltercontion beginwith to contains?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, devexpress, xtragrid

I am using **devexpress 16.1** version, enable ***autofilter*** mode using **columnheader**, when i  enter values its filter by begin character, but i want to filter contains, for example , i want to get "**manager**", i will enter "**nage**". am tried with this, but while filtering my filter values are empty

```
 Dim filterstr As String = GridView1.FocusedValue
 GridView1.ActiveFilterString = "Contains([" & HitColumnName & "]" & "," & "'" & filterstr & "'" & ")"
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the filter condition in the [OptionsColumn.AutoFilterCondition](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridColumnsOptionsColumnFilter_AutoFilterConditiontopic) property for every *column* in GridView.

I suggest you to go through documentation of XtraGrid [Filtering](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/3501/Controls-and-Libraries/Data-Grid/Filtering-and-Locating-Rows/Filtering):
[Tutorial: Column Filter Dropdowns](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/114639/Controls-and-Libraries/Data-Grid/Filtering-and-Locating-Rows/Filtering/Tutorials/Tutorial-Column-Filter-Dropdowns)
[Tutorial: Data Filtering Basics and Filter Panel Settings](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/114643/Controls-and-Libraries/Data-Grid/Filtering-and-Locating-Rows/Filtering/Tutorials/Tutorial-Data-Filtering-Basics-and-Filter-Panel-Settings)

You can set it in Designer in column properties:
[image]

and pragmatically as below:

```
gridView1.Columns[0].OptionsFilter.AutoFilterCondition = DevExpress.XtraGrid.Columns.AutoFilterCondition.Contains;
```

**References:**
[XtraGrid - Provide a property to change filtering type from "begins with" to "contains", etc.](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/S134951/xtragrid-provide-a-property-to-change-filtering-type-from-begins-with-to-contains-etc)
[How to set filter condition as CONTAINS for AutoFilter row through code at grid level](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q293771/how-to-set-filter-condition-as-contains-for-autofilter-row-through-code-at-grid-level)
[How to set auto filter row text of specific columns via code](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q292542/how-to-set-auto-filter-row-text-of-specific-columns-via-code)

Comment: hello niranjan, optioncolumns.autofiltercondition option not with my grid-view, i checked that, is there any solution to achieve the filter option